# Redirecting specific default.aspx to / through web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, web-config

Our website has this structure:

> http://localhost/default.aspx
>
> http://localhost/aboutus/default.aspx
>
> http://localhost/resources/default.aspx
>
> http://localhost/mobile/default.aspx

When I added the following rule to web.config, it is redirecting all the default.aspx to /

```
    <rule name="Default Document" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)default.aspx" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
```

I only want only two of these urls to redirect to /

> http://localhost/default.aspx redirects to http://localhost/
>
> http://localhost/mobile/default.aspx redirects to http://localhost/mobile/

Can you please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: any suggestions? help

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
                <rule name="root homemobile" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^mobile/Default.aspx" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/mobile/" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="root home" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
                    <match url="Default.aspx" ignoreCase="true"  /> 
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
                </rule>
```